# Add all commits from GitLab merge request to Upsource review

Tags: git, gitlab, upsource, git-history-graph

I have GitLab MR and I want to review these changes in Upsource (I want to merge the changes from `feature` to `rc`). `feature` contains commits `2, 4, 6, 8`. But when I clicked `Create branch review` on my MR branch, not all committs from MR were exported to review.

[image: Grapaph]

I tried to solve the problem in 3 different ways:

1. When the review is created by `Create branch review`, only commit `8` is added, because the branch `fix` was created from commit `6` (same thing happens when using the search request `only-branch: {feature}`). MR commits: `2, 4, 6, 8`
2. If I try to add revisions through search `branch: {feature}` I get commits `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8` because this search adds commits from all the branches that were merged into `feature`. MR commits: `2, 4, 6, 8`
3. I can use request `branch: {feature} and not branch: rc` and get all the commits I want, but I must add `and not branch:` to this request for all the branches that were merged into `feature`. And I still have a promlem - I can't use `select all` checkbox. There is no way to load all the commits that comply with the request, only 20 commits were loaded by cliking `more` button.

Could you please tell me the easiest way to add all MR GitLab commits to Upsource review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Upsource (2017.3) features [much deeper integration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-9358) with GitLab. If you enable synchronization for this project, Upsource will automatically create reviews for open pull requests taking the commits list via GitLab API, rather than from commit history. Besides you can create merge requests from Upsource UI.

Try the [latest build](http://download.jetbrains.com/upsource/upsource-2017.3.2679.zip).

Comment: Thanks, now I am using 2017.2 version, going to update it.